# Model.fit raises error - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, model-fitting

I'm new to CRNN model and I'm currently working on a text recognition project. However when using `model.fit()` method I got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'.` As I know the new version of `model.fit()` supports generator as input. But I still got the problem.

I'm using Tensorflow version 2.6.4

This is my code

```
class DataGenerator(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, img_dirpath, img_w, img_h,
                 batch_size,n,output_labels,max_text_len=15):
        # I put out some code 

    def build_data(self):

    def next_data(self): 
        

    def next_batch(self):
   
        while True:
            X_data = np.ones([self.batch_size, self.img_w, self.img_h, 1])  
            
            Y_data = np.ones([self.batch_size, self.max_text_len])        
           
            input_length = np.ones((self.batch_size, 1)) * 40
            label_length = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 1))                   
            source_str=[]                                                   
            for i in range(self.batch_size):
                img, text = self.next_data() #getting the image and text data pointed by current index
                                    
                img=img.T
                img = np.expand_dims(img, -1) 
                X_data[i] = img
                label=encode_words_labels(text) 
                lbl_len=len(label)
                Y_data[i,0:lbl_len] = label 
                label_length[i] = len(label)
                source_str.append(text) 
            
        #Preparing the input for the Model
            inputs = {
                'img_input': X_data,  
                'ground_truth_labels': Y_data,  
                'input_length': input_length,  
                'label_length': label_length,
                'source_str': source_str  # used for visualization only
            }
            #Preparing output for the Model and intializing to zeros
            outputs = {'ctc': np.zeros([self.batch_size])}  
            print(type(inputs))
            yield (inputs, outputs) # Return the Prepared input and output to the Model
```

This is the part where the error appears:

```
img_text_recog.fit(x = train_gene.next_batch(),
                    steps_per_epoch=int(train_gene.n / batch_size),
                    epochs=20,
                    callbacks=[viz_cb_train,viz_cb_val,train_gene,val_gen,tensorboard_callback,early_stop,model_chk_pt],
                    validation_data=val_gen.next_batch(),
                    validation_steps=int(val_gen.n / batch_size))
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_54/2615878982.py in <module>
      4                     callbacks=[viz_cb_train,viz_cb_val,train_gene,val_gen,tensorboard_callback,early_stop,model_chk_pt],
      5                     validation_data=val_gen.next_batch(),
----> 6                     validation_steps=int(val_gen.n / batch_size))
...
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I think the problem lies in the input/output but I cannot find out how to solve it

Comment: This is due to  the `val_gen` dataset containing string and is not converted to numpy array before fitting into the model for training. Please let us know what the `val_gen` dataset looks like or how you pre-processed the `val_gen` dataset?